# NPM ERR! CODE EINTEGRITY when i run create react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-cache

I tried starting a new react project and i kept getting this error

```
 npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/default-gateway: Integrity verification failed for sha512-XNq1bW+TSjcWkvLm57AQGDZuMWP+o91SzJFSO/wm6OJyCzHQBgEh6ltY91FHduphvXq1p6szX47GjsuhU2W05Q== (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\5c\da\b56d6f934a371692f2e6e7b01018366e3163fea3dd52cc91523bfc26e8e2720b31d0060121ea5b58f7514776ea61bd7ab5a7ab335f8ec68ecba15365b4e5)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-15T07_32_25_495Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
```

i have tried updating NPM but it just does not seem to work!

Comment: Try 'npm cache verify' or 'npm i -g npm' or possibly removing the npm/npm-cache folders and completely reinstalling again.

Comment: Try to set this command npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This worked for me:**

npm cache verify

**or you can try**

npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It worked for me after removing the spaces in the directories name,
e.g.
`C:\Users\LENOVO\React Projects\webapp`
becomes
`C:\Users\LENOVO\React_Projects\webapp`